QGIS 3.36 - Adding Basemaps - Tile request max retry error. Failed 3 requests for tile 1 of tileRequest 2
I have been trying to add basemaps in QGIS 3.36, via both Quick Map Services plugin and XYZ Tiles.
But get the following error:
WARNING    Tile request max retry error. Failed 3 requests for tile 1 of tileRequest 2 (url: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x=0&y=0&z=1)

Any suggestions? Thanks!
EDIT: I have uninstalled QGIS 3.36 (+application support folder), and installed QGIS. 3.34, still same error. Also not able to connect to the QGIS Official plugin repository (status = unavailable), possibly related?
Thanks!
